# Request failed. Input string was not in correct format. Updating list Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am trying to update a List on sharepoint.

When I clientContext.executeAsync runs I get a QueryFailed answer saying "Request failed. Input string was not in correct format. undefined.

I've checked the type of the inputs are the same as on the list.

```
function submitReview(){
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(hostweblink);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Frequently Asked Questions');

    var oListItem = oList.getItemById(table_faqs[questionIndex].Title);
    oListItem.set_item('reviewAvg', table_faqs[questionIndex].reviewAvg+=selectedRaiting);
    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);

    function onQuerySucceeded(){
        alert("Item Updated!");
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
    '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
}
```

Comment: Which input field gives the error?

Comment: It doesn't say, It just says whatever the onQueryFailed alert displays which is "Request failed. Input string was not in the correct format. undefined"

Comment: If you are doing getItemById, why are you passing a Title? Is your Title the same as the ID that gets assigned on the back end? If not, you need to find the ID of the entry you want to use and pass a valid ID number.

Comment: In addition to what Matt said, please double check the new value of reviewAvg property.

Comment: Yes @Matt it is the same ID as the one from the Backend, I've also checked the value on reviewAvg